# Visual Studio 2012/2013 XSL XPATH Project

Tags: templates, xslt, xpath, project

I have problem with Visual Studio 2013, I want to use MS IDE to create projects for XSLT.
On start I need Project Template for XSLT language but there is only C# C++ VB.

How to add/create new language tab(XSLT) and tamplates for Project selection ?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that there is no such thing as an XSLT *project* in Visual Studio. Had you heard somewhere that there is such a thing?

You can create and debug XSLT *files* by going to File > New > File... > General > XSLT File.

[image: File dialog XSLT]

You can also add XSLT files to many different kinds of Visual Studio projects through this same process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web forms project and then add an XSLT file to get full IDE syntactical support. So

File > New > Project > C# (on left hand side) > Web Forms (on right pane) and click Ok. Once project loads then  right click and choose add and choose New Item. Then scroll down in dialog to XSLT file. Finally click Add.